# Identify this wall texture please. Thanks!

Tags: patching-drywall, texture

I need to match this wall texture to fix some damage and also to cover some larger areas of new remodeling construction. The house was built in 1963 in Texas.

Any help identifying and/or techniques to use is greatly appreciated.

I added two more photos with a 4 inch wide putty knife for perspective here:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/cs9PJRMkcZMWnZ8j6

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have seen this done with what I call a *plaster brush*. Marshalltown (no affiliation) makes the one shown below. Soft bristles that can be loaded with thinned down mud and applied by hitting it flat against the wall (and not *brushing* with it).

That said- no easy job to have to match a hand done texture like that.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Kyle!